# Screenspace Reflections viewport VS render

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I get two different results for the screenspace reflections. Behind the "moon" I have set up a dark background plane.

- In the viewport it gets reflected and makes the marked area darker.
- In the final render the HDRI background image takes over and cancels that dark area out.

I tried a reflection probe, that that cancels out the HDRI reflections. Does anybody know how I can get the viewport result in the final render?

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Probably better to share your simplified file via https://blend-exchange.com